# How to display the creation dates only once

Tags: python, django, sqlite

When I create an item, I automatically add the creation date. The `body` is written to the body itself, it is saved in the database and then displayed. And the creation time is automatically added to `created_at`. I need to display all the dates under which any items were created in sorted order.

-- models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Todo(models.Model):
   body = models.TextField()
   created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

--views.py

```
def all(request):
   date = Todo.objects.order_by('created_at')
   return render(request, 'todo/all.html', {'date':date})
```

In the view, I try to use order_by and output it in the template

--all.html

```
{% for date in date %}
   <h1>{{ date.created_at }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

Then I get this situation. This is practically what I need, but the output depends on the number of items under each date, and I just need to print the date once, that is, `Oct. 13,2018` and `Oct.14,2018`, each date once, how to achieve this result?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first convert the datetime to date and then write an orm which would order it by the date field and then use a distinct to uniquely get all the dates.

Your code should look something like this:

```
popular = Todo.objects.extra(select={'custom_dt': 'to_date(created_at)'}).values_list('custom_dt', flat=True).order_by('-custom_dt').distinct()
```

For SQLite:

```
popular = Todo.objects.extra(select={'custom_dt': 'strftime("%d-%m-%Y", "created_at")'}).values_list('custom_dt', flat=True).order_by('-custom_dt').distinct()
```

Comment: have this - DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend. custom_dt what is it?

Comment: @karaname I have updated the answer. Can you test now?

Comment: have this - no such function: to_date

Comment: which  datebase are you  using?

Comment: db.sqlite3, Do I need to change on postgreSQL or mySQL ?

Comment: you need to use `'strftime("%d-%m-%Y", "created_at")'` for sqllite. I  have  updated the answer.

Comment: @karaname my pleasure. Kindly upvote and accept the answer.